# Displaying BLOB from Firebird query in PHP file

Tags: php, firebird

I am having trouble display a BLOB field from a Firebird query in my HTML table.

The field contains: "Sweeping floors."

In the HTML table it shows as: "0x00ea9572000001ec "

The BLOB only contains characters. Based on that I found the line of code `cast(RECORDEDNOTES as blob sub_type text character set utf8) as CONVERTED_RECORDEDNOTES` where I changed the field name and added an alias but I got the error below. I also tried: `cast(RECORDEDNOTES as VARCHAR(250)) as CONVERTED_RECORDEDNOTES`

Both created the error:

> Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Token unknown - line 2, column
> 45,

which is where the code started in the SQL statement.

The latter worked in DBeaver, but in PHP it created the above error as opposed to an incorrect output.

How do I convert my BLOB data? Do I do it in the query or with the resulting query data?

Comment: Please add the PHP code.

Comment: The value you get is the blob ID. The content of blobs need to be explicitly retrieved (using [`ibase_blob_open`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-blob-open.php), and then one or more [`ibase_blob_get`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-blob-get.php) or [`ibase_blob_echo`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-blob-echo.php), followed by an [`ibase_blob_close`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-blob-close.php)). Also, the error you show is incomplete: it is missing the unknown token.

Comment: In any case, you need to provide a [mre].

Comment: @MarkRotteveel you"ve given me enough information to send me in the right direction, so know I have the answer. I only required these there lines of code.
$blob_data = ibase_blob_open($row['RECORDEDNOTES']);
$blob_contents = ibase_blob_get($blob_data, 250);

Comment: I highly recommend you post an answer to that effect (I don't program in PHP myself, so I don't want to try).

Answer (score 0):

I use the following PHP function I've written for Firebird SQL. It works perfectly for me for queries with and withoud BLOB fields to retrieve their records. It detects if there are any BLOB fields in the given query. During reading the records, if there is a BLOB field, it will read the contents of that BLOB field. It can handle queries without and with (multiple) BLOB fields.

```
function selectSQLarray($sql) {
    $dataArr = array();
    /* Attempt to connect to Firebird database */
    $link = ibase_connect (DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

    $rid = @ibase_query ($link, $sql);
    if ($rid===false) var_dump($sql); //errorHandle(ibase_errmsg(),$sql);
    
    $coln = ibase_num_fields($rid);
    $blobFields = array();

    /* Get all blob fields from result */
    for ($i=0; $i < $coln; $i++) {
        $col_info = ibase_field_info($rid, $i);
        if ($col_info["type"]=="BLOB") $blobFields[$i] = $col_info["name"];
    }

    /* Read each row from query result */
    while ($row = ibase_fetch_object ($rid)) {
        /* put each blob data into the field */
        foreach ($blobFields as $field_num=>$field_name) {
            try {
                $blobid = ibase_blob_open($row->$field_name);
                if ($blobid == false) {
                    $row->$field_name = '';
                } else {
                    $row->$field_name = ibase_blob_get($blobid,102400);
                    ibase_blob_close($blobid);
                }
            }
                catch(Trowable $t) {
                    $row->$field_name = '';
                }
        }
        $dataArr[] = $row;
    }
    ibase_close ($link);
    return $dataArr;
}
```